# No domain values in CL_SALV_TABLE column. Why?

Tags: abap, alv

I have 2 rows shown in the ALV list, one of this column has domain values.

[image]

If I click on the search help right it doesn't show any values at all.

Do I have to activate something in the class to see the values of any domain?

Comment: That's probably because this field does not any search help at all. Check your table line structure for this ALV.

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe. Show us the code (and the structure)...

Comment: Do you create fieldcatalog manually or by FM? From what structure?

Comment: It is not field catalog. it is just an internal table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic search help (aka domain values) will be showed **only** when creating ALV via Dictionary structure, and that's why it is impossible with `cl_salv_table`, because it accepts only internal table.
However, it have special method `set_ddic_reference` for assigning F4 values.

```
DATA: lr_column   TYPE REF TO cl_salv_column_table,
       lr_columns TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table.
DATA: ls_ddic type salv_s_ddic_reference.
lr_columns = o_alv->get_columns( ).
lr_column ?= lr_columns->get_column( columnname = 'MANDT' ).
ls_ddic-table = 'T001'.
ls_ddic-field = 'MANDT'.
lr_column->set_ddic_reference( ls_ddic ).
lr_column->set_f4( abap_true ).
```

This code should be called after the factory constructor and before the **display()** method.

Comment: Search help called H_T000. Transaction code SE11: T001, Field: MANDT, Tab: Input Help, Srch Help: H_T000.

Comment: Read the API, it accepts not the search help name, but field name. And try the code before posting comments